# How does marking down get calculated?

Tags: support

Today, I've had two down markings of 2 each, and one of 15. I'm really past caring about downvoters, but the sums just don't add up (or down...). What calculations am I not understanding please? the -15 contained one downvote.

Comment: An accepted answer got removed so you lost the +15 rep for it. It shows up [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/users/2808/tim?tab=reputation).

Comment: Thanks Dom. Simple way to access that screen?

Comment: Not that I know of. Someone on Meta.SE might have more info for you.